# Hi, I am trying to write a program that shows whether a year is a leap or not and if it is what the sum of its digits is

Tags: c

I understand the line of code that is used to determine if something is a leap year or not and I've seen the line of code to determine the sum of numbers but I don't know how to combine the two. When I run it I get an error saying

```
In function "main":
error. "else" without a previous "if"
error. "else" without a previous "if"
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int year,sum=0,r;

    printf("Enter a year to check if it is a leap year\n");
    scanf("%d", &year);
    if ( year%400 == 0)
        for(;year!=0;year=year/10){
            r=year%10;
            sum=sum+r;
        }
    printf("%d is a leap year and the sum is %d.\n", year,sum);
    else if ( year%100 == 0)
        printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);
    else if ( year%4 == 0 )
        for(;year!=0;year=year/10){
            r=year%10;
            sum=sum+r;
        }
    printf("%d is a leap year and the sum is %d.\n", year,sum);
    else
        printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indent your code and maybe you will see where the mismatches lie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of problems in your code-

Problem no. 1 -

"if" statements in your program contain multiple statements but you have not enclosed them in {}.

Problem no. 2 -

You are modifying the value of "year" variable and printing it if the year found as a leap year. So, the value of year will always be printed as 0.
Take the backup of variable "year" value and then do your steps to calculate the sum and in the printf print the backup value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int year,sum=0,r;
    int year_val;

    printf("Enter a year to check if it is a leap year\n");
    scanf("%d", &year);
    year_val = year;

    if ( year%400 == 0) {
            for(;year!=0;year=year/10){
                    r=year%10;
                    sum=sum+r;
            }
            printf("%d is a leap year and the sum is %d.\n", year_val,sum);
    } else if ( year%100 == 0)
            printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);
    else if ( year%4 == 0 ) {
            for(;year!=0;year=year/10){
                    r=year%10;
                    sum=sum+r;
            }
            printf("%d is a leap year and the sum is %d.\n", year_val,sum);
    } else
            printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you do not use the block syntax with `{` `}` pairs for some of the `if` statements.  You later inserted some extra `printf` statements, breaking the syntax.

Given your skill level, it is a good idea to always use the block syntax for all compound statements. IMHO, even advanced programmers should not use the single statement syntax for anything but the simplest compound statements, if at all.

The output is incorrect for the `year` because you modify the variable in the `for` loop. Use another variable for this calculation.

Here is the modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int year, sum = 0, y, r;

    printf("Enter a year to check if it is a leap year\n");
    scanf("%d", &year);
    if (year % 400 == 0) {
        for (y = year; y != 0; y = y / 10) {
            r = y % 10;
            sum = sum + r;
        }
        printf("%d is a leap year and the sum is %d.\n", year, sum);
    } else
    if (year % 100 == 0) {
        printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);
    } else
    if (year % 4 == 0) {
        for (y = year; y != 0; y = y / 10) {
            r = year % 10;
            sum = sum + r;
        }
        printf("%d is a leap year and the sum is %d.\n", year, sum);
    } else {
        printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the code can be simplified with a compound test for the leap year (according the the Gregorian calendar):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int year, sum, y, r;

    printf("Enter a year to check if it is a leap year\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &year) == 1) {
        if (year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)) {
            for (sum = 0, y = year; y != 0; y = y / 10) {
                r = y % 10;
                sum = sum + r;
            }
            printf("%d is a leap year and the sum is %d.\n", year, sum);
        } else {
            printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);
        }
    } else {
        printf("input error.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of syntax errors in your code. First try to write clean code.

Here are the errors you need to correct

a) Remove the extra semicolon on line 5 
b) Add braces {} for the if statement on line 8,18 
c) Add a temp variable to hold the year so that if the year is leap year,
 
   you can print temp there. Because the year variable will then be reduced to 0.

> I just corrected the above mentioned things and now your code works like charm!

Here is the modified code. Take details of the braces {}

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int year,sum=0,r;

    printf("Enter a year to check if it is a leap year\n");
    scanf("%d", &year);
    int temp = year;
    if ( year%400 == 0){
      for(;year!=0;year=year/10){
        r=year%10;
        sum=sum+r;
        }
    printf("%d is a leap year and the sum is %d.\n", temp,sum);
    }
    else if ( year%100 == 0)
        printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);
    else if ( year%4 == 0 ){
        for(;year!=0;year=year/10){
            r=year%10;
            sum=sum+r;
        }
    printf("%d is a leap year and the sum is %d.\n", temp,sum);
    }

    else
        printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);  
    return 0;
}
```